# optional parameters in abstract class type signature

Tags: f#, abstract-class, optional-parameters

The Class:

```
type NotAbstract () = 
    member this.WithOptionalParameters (x, ?y) = 
        let y = defaultArg y 10
        x + y
```

has the following type signature:

```
type NotAbstract =
  class
    new : unit -> NotAbstract
    member WithOptionalParameters : x:int * ?y:int -> int
  end
```

However, this does not work:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type AbstractExample () = 
    abstract WithOptionalParameters: int * ?int -> int /// Ouch...

type NotAbstract () = 
    inherit AbstractExample ()
    override this.WithOptionalParameters (x, ?y) = 
        let y = defaultArg y 10
        x + y
```

How to write the proper type signature in the abstract definition of a function with optional parameters? I did not find any hint [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483471.aspx).

PS: I am aware that (similar) result could be achieved with [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism)

Comment: The F# way is to use Option types instead of the (more primitive) Nullable types.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is but there are two important cases where you need optionals: Fable bindings and C# interop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declaring an argument as Option type doesn't really make the argument optional.

```
NotAbstract().WithOptionalParameters(2)
// This expression was expected to have type
//     int * Option<int>    
// but here has type
//     int
```

The [spec §8.13.6](http://fsharp.org/about/files/spec.pdf) has it:

> In a signature, optional arguments appear as follows:
>   `static member OneNormalTwoOptional : arg1:int * ?arg2:int * ?arg3:int -> int`

Naming your optional argument in the abstract member signature thus

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type AbstractExample () = 
    abstract WithOptionalParameters: int * ?y:int -> int      

type NotAbstract () = 
    inherit AbstractExample ()
    override this.WithOptionalParameters (x, ?y) = 
        let y = defaultArg y 10
        x + y

NotAbstract().WithOptionalParameters(42)  // val it : int = 52
```

Answer (score 4):

Optional parameters are compiled to `Option` types, use `Option<int>` instead of `?int`:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type AbstractExample () = 
    abstract WithOptionalParameters: int * Option<int> -> int      

type NotAbstract () = 
    inherit AbstractExample ()
    override this.WithOptionalParameters (x, ?y) = 
        let y = defaultArg y 10
        x + y
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is true. I edited your answer to fix my own error in the type signature of `WithOptionalParameters` which actually returns an `int`.

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis Ok thanks for the edit, I din't check the code before pasting it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type AbstractExample () = 
    abstract WithOptionalParameters: int * Nullable<int> -> unit
```

[In F#, there's no syntactical sugar for nullable types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/946836/126014), so although you can declare a *value* nullable with the `?y` syntax, you can't do that for a *type*. Instead, you'll have to use `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: s/declare a *value* nullable/declare a value optional/ ?

Comment: Either I misread the original question, or made some other cognitive error along the way, but I ended up thinking this was the solution. Obviously, the right answer is the one provided by polkduran, but I thought I'd just leave my answer here, in the off chance it could ever help someone else...

Comment: @Mark The `?arg` syntax in F# does not "make a value nullable". It declares an element of a tupled method parameter as optional for F# clients. However, non-F# clients will see it as `FSharpOption<...>`. This is different from the `?Type` syntax in C#, which declares a value type as nullable, which appears to all CLI clients, including F#, as `Nullable<...>`. The two concepts have nothing to do with each other...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Yes, makes sense - esp with the context. +1 as it [with the explanation] adds variety without misleading.